# Custom parsing pattern to get data from multiline log files in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Will need to ingest our custom log files into `Elasticsearch via Logstash`, It's getting difficulty to write the correct custom parsing syntax in logstash to get the expected data out of my logs, as can be seen will need those 4-5 values in `json format` to feed into Elasticsearch.

Refer the log file format.

> Timestamp: 2/4/2016 12:11:41 PM
>   Title:xyz()
>   Message: Product ABX8364 has been added in cart 
>   Machine: USNGDY22

---

> Timestamp: 3/4/2016 12:11:42 PM
>   Title:xyzzz()
>   Message: Product ZX8364 has been removed from cart 
>   Machine: USNGDY22

---

> Timestamp: 3/4/2016 12:11:42 PM
>   Title:xyzzz()
>   Message: Product ZX8364 has been removed from cart 
>   StackTrace: at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)....
>   Machine: USNGDY22

Comment: There's a very helpful online tool to help you land your grok: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ That + the [list of grok patterns](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#) and you can whip your grok easily. Try it out

Comment: It looks like you have a single message, which is good.  What is the "expected data"?  What have you tried?

Comment: @AlainCollins: I m expecting the values for Timestamp, Title, Message and StackTrace, Kindly note these are multiline logs will have each of these values in a new line, Something messed up in the question while formatting the logs

Comment: Then your first step is to get them into one line.  Filebeat supports multiline, or look into logstash's mutliline codec.  Once you get there, then start using grok{}.

Comment: Thank you @AlainCollins for the direction, Using the multiline now we got the event in single line, But getting difficulty to get the values from the message string, below is the message format, I am expecting values like timestamp, title, message and machine fields values from string. 

"----------------------------------------\r\nTimestamp: 4/16/2016 3:40:11 PM\r\nTitle:CountryService.GetCountries()\r\nMessage: Received request to get country list\r\nMachine: INS\r\n\r"

Comment: You need to use the grok{} filter to extract the values from your message field.

Comment: @AlainCollins: could you help to write the grok syntax to get these values?